# Google Cloud Tasks drops tasks on a 302 response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

Cloud Tasks drops HTTP tasks when the target returns a 302 response.

I have a Google Cloud Tasks client that generates HTTP tasks to trigger a Google Cloud Function (GCF). When the target function is available, everything works fine. But, when the function is not deployed (due to deployment errors or any other issues), GCF service returns a 302 response (as documented here https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#login) which the Cloud Tasks Service interprets as an OK and removes the task from the queue.

```
attemptResponseLog: {
dispatchCount: "1"
maxAttempts: 0
responseCount: "1"
scheduleTime: "2022-05-23T22:43:12.385523Z"
status: "OK"
targetAddress: "POST https://us-central1-<<myprojectid>>.cloudfunctions.net/foo_task"
targetType: "HTTP"
}
```

This inability to properly interpret a 302 causes tasks get dropped instead of getting queued when the target function does not exist.

I confirmed that the task does not exist using gcloud cli as well as curl:

```
$ gcloud functions call foo_task
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.call) ResponseError: status=[404], code=[Ok], message=[Function foo_task in region us-central1 in project <<myprojectid>> does not exist]
```

```
$ curl -I https://us-central1-<<myprojectid>>.cloudfunctions.net/foo_task 
HTTP/2 302 
location: https://us-central1-<<myprojectid>>.cloudfunctions.net/_ah/conflogin?continue=https://us-central1-<<myprojectid>>.cloudfunctions.net/foo_task
x-cloud-trace-context: de989ddd4748422a1e194c290f9a9150
date: Mon, 23 May 2022 23:04:57 GMT
content-type: text/html
server: Google Frontend
```

Does anyone know of a workaround ?

Adding **client code** that creates tasks:

```
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();
const GCP_PROJECT = process.env.GCP_PROJECT || "testproject123";
const QUEUE_LOCATION = process.env.QUEUE_LOCATION || "us-central1";
const QUEUE_NAME = process.env.QUEUE_NAME || "http-tasks";
const FUNCTION_URL = process.env.FUNCTION_URL || "https://us-central1-testproject123.cloudfunctions.net/foo_task";
const TASK_DELAY_SECONDS = process.env.TASK_DELAY_SECONDS || 10;

async function createHttpTask(project, location, queue, url, payload, delaySeconds) {

  // Construct the fully qualified queue name.
  const parent = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue);

  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url,
    },
  };

  if (payload) {
    task.httpRequest.body = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
    task.httpRequest.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  }

  if (delaySeconds) {
    // The time when the task is scheduled to be attempted.
    task.schedule_time = {
      seconds: delaySeconds + Date.now() / 1000,
    };
  }

  // Send create task request.
  console.log('Sending task:');
  console.log(task);
  const request = {parent: parent, task: task};
  const [response] = await tasksClient.createTask(request);
  console.log(`Created task ${response.name}`);
}

createHttpTask(GCP_PROJECT, QUEUE_LOCATION, QUEUE_NAME, FUNCTION_URL, "Foo Bar", TASK_DELAY_SECONDS );
```

Comment: Writing a custom HTTP Task Handler instead of relying on GCF service could be a workaround. But, if Cloud Tasks doesn't deal with a 302 properly, is it a sign that Cloud Tasks has many more hidden issues that will show up later in other scenarios.

Comment: Cloud Tasks in not interpreting a 302 as OK. Cloud Tasks receives a 302 and then goes to the new **Location**. That location is returning **HTTP 200 OK**. You will need to implement something else that determines your app is not deployed or functioning correctly.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. I was looking for a config that would instruct Cloud Tasks not to follow redirects. Do you know if there is one ?

Comment: Can you share your code for us to replicate on our end?

Comment: @CatherineO I have added the code. Before you execute the code, please make sure you replace "testproject123" and "npm i @google-cloud/tasks"

Comment: Hi @vijaypm, to add some inputs on your code, before calling the createHttpTask, create a code that triggers the function then check the response status code if it's HTTP 200. If it's status 200, then that's the time you call the createHttpTask.